# Javascript | P5.JS Library - Snake Game (X) Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am coding / following a snake game coding tutorial and seemed to have hit a point where I have found an error that the instructor hasn't encountered, and I seem to not understand the origin of the problem.

I have even commented each line describing the function each line has to maybe help me figure out the problem but I have blanked out.

The line with the problem is clearly pointed out.

Full Error From Chrome Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
>   --at Snake.show (snake:95)
>   --at draw (snake:37)
>   --at p5.redraw (p5.js:17153)
>   --at p5. (p5.js:12358)

Specific Problematic Line:

> rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);  // Draw The Tail At The End.

When I either run into a border wall or run into myself by going the opposite direction I was initially going in with 3+ length of the tail I get this error.
Can someone explain whats causing this error? It must be something to do with the death aspect.

Full Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Snake Game</title>
        <script src="http://sethjfreeman.com/resources/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://sethjfreeman.com/resources/P5/p5.js"></script>
        <link href="http://sethjfreeman.com/projects/snake.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>  <!-- Uses p5.js Javascript Library -->
            var s;  // Snake Character.
            var scl = 20;   // Size Of Everything.
            var food;   // Food Items. Makes Em Grow When Eatin.

            function setup() {
                createCanvas($(window).width() - 10, $(window).height() - 10);  // Creates De Canvas For Everything To Be In.
                s = new Snake();  // Creates A New Snake | Calls Snake Function To Create A Snake |.
                frameRate(10);  // Sloooowwwssss Down The Game To Actully Be Able To Control The Snake.
                pickLocation(); // Calls Pick Location To Pick A Location For The First Food Item To Be Placed.
            }

            function pickLocation() {  // A Function To Control Where The Food Goes
                var cols = floor(width / scl);  // Creates An Imaginary Vertical Grid Every 20 Pixels. Floor Is Being Used To Prevent A Column From Being Placed At E.G: 40.6 Pixels.
                var rows = floor(height / scl);  // Creates An Imaginary Horizontal Gird Every 20 Pixels. Floor Is Being Used To Prevent A Column From Being Placed At E.G: 40.6 Pixels.
                food = createVector(floor(random(cols)), floor(random(rows)));  // Assigns Food To Being At The Random Location.
                food.mult(scl);  // Makes Sure The Food Vector Is Set In The 20 Pixels Guide Lines. Not The 20.5 Pixel Guide Lines.
            }

            function draw() {  // Controls Everything That Is Being Drawn To The Canvas.
                background(51);  // Sets Background To Be A Grayscale Value. 

                if(s.eat(food)) {  // Checks If Food Was Eatin, If True Picks A New Location For A Food Peice.
                    pickLocation();  // Calls Pick Locatoin Function.
                }
                s.death();  // Calls Death Function.
                s.update();  // Calls Update Function.
                s.show();  // Calls Show Function.

                fill(255, 0, 100);  // Sets Food's Background Color.
                rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);  // Creates A New Food Item.
            }

            function Snake() {  // Controls Everything To Do With De Snake Character.
                this.x = 0;  // Holds The X Pos Of Player.
                this.y = 0;  // Holds The Y Pos Of The Player.
                this.xspeed = 1;  // Moves Player (X) Speed.
                this.yspeed = 0;  // Moves Player (X) Speed.
                this.total = 0;  // Holds The Amount Of Squares On Snake.
                this.tail = [];  // History For Where Each Part Of The Body Needs To Go.

                this.dir = function(x, y) {  // Controls The Direction Of The Snake.
                    this.xspeed = x;  // Recives The Intput From keyPressed.
                    this.yspeed = y;  // Recives The Intput From keyPressed.
                }

                this.eat = function(pos) {  // Controls What Happens When A Food Item Was Eatin.
                    var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);  // Holds The Distance Between Two Points, In This Case, Between The Snake & The Food Item.
                    if(d < 1) {  // If The Distance Is Less Than 1 Pixel From Food Item Add 1 To Total. 
                        this.total++;
                        return true;
                    } else {  // Else Go To Sleep.
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                this.death = function() {  // Controls When The Player Dies.
                    for(var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {  // Loops Through Snake Length. Loop Used For Checking If Snake Runs Into Self.
                        var pos = this.tail[i];  // Checks Position Of Each Square Of Tail
                        var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);  // Holds The Distance Between Two Points, In This Case, Between The Snake Head & The Particular Spot On The Tail Thats Being Hit.
                        if(d < 1) {  // If The Pixel Between The Distance, Restart The Player.
                            total = 0;  // Resets Total.
                            this.tail = [];  // Resets Tail.
                        }
                    }
                }

                this.update =  function() {  // Updates Everything. Simple Right?
                    if(this.total === this.tail.length) {  
                        for(var i = 0; i < this.tail.length - 1; i++) {  //  Loops Through Whole Snake Besides Head.
                            this.tail[i] = this.tail[i + 1];  // Shifts Each Body Square Location By 1.
                        }
                    }
                    this.tail[this.total - 1] = createVector(this.x, this.y);

                    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;  // The X Cords Of Snake Changes Depending On X Speed * The Scale Of The Snake
                    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;  // The Y Cords Of Snake Changes Depending On Y Speed * The Scale Of The Snake

                    this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - scl);  // Constrains The Snake Between The Left Border And Right Border Of The Sceen
                    this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - scl);  // Constrains The Snake Between The Top Border And Bottom Border Of The Sceen
                }
                /*
                    _____  _____   ____  ____  _      ______ __  __ 
                    |  __ \|  __ \ / __ \|  _ \| |    |  ____|  \/  |
                    | |__) | |__) | |  | | |_) | |    | |__  | \  / |
                    |  ___/|  _  /| |  | |  _ <| |    |  __| | |\/| |
                    | |    | | \ \| |__| | |_) | |____| |____| |  | |
                    |_|    |_|  \_\\____/|____/|______|______|_|  |_|

                */
                this.show = function() {
                    fill(255);  // Draw The Tail White.
                    for(var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {  // Draw The Tail.
                        rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);  // Draw The Tail At The End.
                    }

                    rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
                }
            }

            function keyPressed() {  // Checks Which Keys Were Pressed.
                if(keyCode === UP_ARROW) {  // If Up Arrow Was Pressed Move Snake Upwards.
                    s.dir(0, -1);  // Because Direction Starts From Left & Top, -1 = Subtract From Top Pos. +1 = Add From Top Pos.
                } else if(keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {  // If Down Arrow Was Pressed Move Snake Downwards.
                    s.dir(0, 1);  // Because Direction Starts From Left & Top, -1 = Subtract From Top Pos. +1 = Add From Top Pos.
                } else if(keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {  // If Right Arrow Was Pressed Move Snake Right.
                    s.dir(1, 0);  // Because Direction Starts From Left & Top, -1 = Subtract From Top Left. +1 = Add From Top Left.
                } else if(keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {  // If Left Arrow Was Pressed Move Snake Left.
                    s.dir(-1, 0);  // Because Direction Starts From Left & Top, -1 = Subtract From Top Left. +1 = Add From Top Left.
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to [debug](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your program. (That tutorial is for Processing, but the basic idea is the same.)

You know your problem is on this line:

```
rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);
```

And you know that your error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`

That tells you that `this.tail[i]` is undefined. This usually means that you're trying to access an index that the `this.tail` array doesn't have (like trying to access index 100 of an array that only contains 10 items).

But just looking at your code, you're only looping to `this.tail.length`, so it's not quite so simple. So now you have to debug your code to find out a few things:

- What is the value of `this.tail.length`?
- What is the value of `i`?
- What is at each index of `this.tail` before you start that loop?

Then you're going to have to debug further to figure out exactly when you change `this.tail`. Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger, or at least tracing through with a piece of paper and a pencil?

You need to go through that process until you understand exactly what's going on. If you can narrow it down to just a few lines that aren't behaving how you expect them to, then please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Even though your comment isn't giving a direct solution I will 100% accept it as the answer because stack overflow isn't about question and answer and more about the process of finding the answer. Which is exactly why I LOVE your answer.

Comment: @SethJ.Freeman I appreciate that, but feel free to keep your question open a bit longer if you want to attract other answers. But coding is definitely about the process of breaking a problem down, so let me know if you want to talk through it as you go. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for getting my train back on the rails. The problem is being caused by the this.death function. When I send the snake in the opposite direction it was initially going in with 3+ tail parts, the head is running into the rest of the body. So if i was going -> and then went <- the ●●□ head would run into the second tail part ●□ then run into the last tail part □ and now the body is gone. Also imagine the head being crushed before the body caught up so once the last tail part caught up with the crushed head there is no snake left and the game is confused where to draw the next tail part.

Comment: @SethJ.Freeman Sounds like you got it figured out. But I wouldn't expect to be able to go left if I'm currently going right, so you might be able to avoid this problem altogether by adding that restriction.